# Result of obj.apply{ func1() } is different than obj.func1()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

In kotlin, `apply{}` is defined as `inline fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T`
I thought the use of this function is to minimize this code

```
obj.func1()
obj.func2()
obj.func3()
...
```

to

```
obj.apply {
    func1()
    func2()
    func3()
}
```

But now I think it has some totally different actual use case. In my android studio project, i got this log

```
2020-12-08 13:3:22.648 28006-28006/com.skb.skara D/VideoViewActivity: onStart: pos 2677
2020-12-08 13:3:22.649 28006-28006/com.skb.skara D/VideoViewActivity: initializePlayer: seeked to 0
2020-12-08 13:3:22.650 28006-28006/com.skb.skara D/VideoViewActivity: onStart: pos 2677
```

for this code

```
private var currentPosition: Int

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart: pos $currentPosition")
    initializePlayer()
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart: pos $currentPosition")
    if (currentPosition == 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart: vid start")
        fullscreen_video.start()
    }
    show()
}

private fun initializePlayer() {
    fullscreen_video.apply {
        setVideoPath(videoUrl)
        seekTo(currentPosition)
        Log.d(TAG, "initializePlayer: seeked to $currentPosition")
    }
}
```

Then I changed `initialisePlayer` function to this

```
private fun initializePlayer() {
    fullscreen_video.setVideoPath(videoUrl)
    fullscreen_video.seekTo(currentPosition)
    Log.d(TAG, "initializePlayer: seeked to $currentPosition")
}
```

and then I got this log

```
2020-12-08 13:12:53.548 28006-28006/com.skb.skara D/VideoViewActivity: onStart: 2677
2020-12-08 13:12:53.550 28006-28006/com.skb.skara D/VideoViewActivity: initializePlayer: seeked to 2677
2020-12-08 13:12:53.550 28006-28006/com.skb.skara D/VideoViewActivity: onStart: 2677
```

Someone please explain this behaviour and also explain the use of scope function `apply{}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful, `VideoView` has its own [currentPosition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView#getCurrentPosition()). Accessing `currentPosition` inside its `apply` block will get the currentPosition of the `VideoView`.

```
private fun initializePlayer() {
    fullscreen_video.apply {
        setVideoPath(videoUrl)
        seekTo(currentPosition) // This will use VideoView.currentPosition
        Log.d(TAG, "initializePlayer: seeked to $currentPosition") // This, too
    }
}
```

Explain about `apply`:

> The context object is available as a receiver (`this`). And `this` always can be omitted.

If you want to access the `currentPosition` you declared above, use `this@YourActivity.currentPosition`. Replace `YourActivity` with your activity.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Solved my problem. I renamed currentPosition to playbackPosition in my activity and now its working properly.

Answer (score 1):

See the table below, within the scope of also, `this.currentPosition` is `fullscreen_video.currentPosition`, instead of your `var currentPosition`

Kotlin's scope operators are like a swiss army knife with a method for every scenario.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html

| Function | Object reference | Return value | Is extension function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| let | it | Lambda result | Yes |
| run | this | Lambda result | Yes |
| run | - | Lambda result | No: called without the context object |
| with | this | Lambda result | No: takes the context object as an argument. |
| apply | this | Context object | Yes |
| also | it | Context object | Yes |

It can be really useful for DSL APIs and also calling multiple setters after creating a simple Java object.

```
    val x = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()).apply {
      init(null as KeyStore?)
    }
```

In this form the incomplete object is never available until fully constructed. So you can assign directly to a field (ignoring concurrency and memory barriers).

But also keeps things in expression form, so you can chain operators instead of having values you mutate imperitively.

Here is an example where `also` is useful instead.

```
fun getRandomInt(): Int {
    return Random.nextInt(100).also {
        writeToLog("getRandomInt() generated value $it")
    }
}
```

If you switch to also, it should make this difference clearer for your case.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. After your answer, I have changed the question. If you able, just again go through the question. :)